# Python 3.5 Extract Digits from Column into New Column

Tags: python, csv, extract, digit

I am trying to extract the last 5 digits of a number in a columun in a CSV and add it as an additional column.  There are more columns in my actual data, and there are thousands of rows of numbers.  For example:

```
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4
3333333, 1234567, 4444444, 5555555
7777777, 7654321, 5555555, 6666666
```

and I want it to be:

```
   Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4, Column 5
   33333333, 1234567,  44444444, 55555555, 34567
   77777777, 7654321,  55555555, 66666666, 54321
```

So far I have tried iterations of findall and think that regex is going to provide the best solution.  I can extract the column, not exactly what I want to do, but so far that is as far as I have gotten.

Comment: what have you got so far ? Have you managed to extract data from a column ? be a bit more specific.

Comment: please show us your code, it is not hard to select only certain values from a string or int. but we need to see how you are extracting your data in the first place to get a clearer understanding of what you need.

Comment: Quemeraisc and WildCard, yes, I am able to move columns and add headers, but I couldn't figure out how to extract only the last part of a column.  Ritesht93's answer worked great.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

print('Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4, Column 5')
with open('data1', 'r') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        print(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[1][-5:], sep=', ')
```

here is the output:

```
$ cat data1 
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4
3333333, 1234567, 4444444, 5555555
7777777, 7654321, 5555555, 6666666
$ python3 a.py 
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4, Column 5
3333333,  1234567,  4444444,  5555555, 34567
7777777,  7654321,  5555555,  6666666, 54321
```

Comment: Ritesht93, I used your example and it worked exactly as needed.  I had been trying some other things, but they didn't work.  Thank you for the fast, reliable answer.